# Error using command "adb install" or "adb push" :device offline

Tags: android, adb, apk, android-virtual-device

I'm using the AVD,I can use command "ls" to see files ,"adb remount" and it shows remount succeeded,but when using "adb push" , error:"device offline",and "Invalid APK file: 1.apk" when using command "adb install"

Here is the cmd output

```
D:\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb remount

remount succeeded

D:\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb shell

root@generic_x86_64:/ # adb install 1.apk

adb install 1.apk

Invalid APK file: 1.apk

255|root@generic_x86_64:/ # adb push 1.apk /sdcard

adb push 1.apk /sdcard

error: device offline

1|root@generic_x86_64:/ #

1|root@generic_x86_64:/ # ls

ls

acct

cache

charger

config

d

data
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute "adb push" and "adb install" from your Windows command prompt, not inside the adb shell - the adb shell runs directly on your phone (emulator) and does not know about Windows.